# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{(ax+1)^b - (bx+1)^a}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{(ax+1)^b - (bx+1)^a}{x^2}$$ where $a, b$ are non-negative integers.

I solved this with the help of L'Hopital's rule, but still I'm looking for a different solution (i.e no L'Hopital's rule). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**
Using the binomial theorem, you have the following approximations
$$(1+ax)^b \approx 1 + abx + \frac{b(b-1)}{2}(ax)^2$$ 
$$(1+bx)^a \approx 1 + abx + \frac{a(a-1)}{2}(bx)^2$$ 
when $x \to 0$. The rest is straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, but... ummmm... do you have any other solution without approximations?

Comment: @Iceghost Well, it's not really an approximation anymore if you write the power series for $(1+u)^{\alpha}$ which is convergent for $|u| <1$. Since $x\to 0$, you can use it because you can work in a small neighborhood that is in the radius of convergence. Then you'll calculate the limit by sending $x\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but your solution and your method don't make sense to me... *crying* Maybe I should wait for a different answer?

Comment: @Iceghost Sure. Why not? It's up to you to decide when your question has been answered convincingly and you don't need to explain your reason to me. If you're still interested in learning this method, you can tell me why it doesn't make sense to you. By the way, if you wish for an algebraic solution, I'm afraid that you'll be disappointed because $(1+u)^{\alpha}$ is far from being algebraic when $\alpha$ is not good. For example, take $\alpha=\sqrt{2}$. So, I think Taylor series is pretty nice for an expression like that.

Comment: Hmm, based on my curriculum I think I should add $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ to the statement

Comment: @Iceghost Then just use $(1+u)^n = \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose{k}} a^k$ which is true for any $u\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks! I was hesitate to do that as I thought I couldn't get rid of these $x$'s but it turned out to be far from easy!

Comment: @Iceghost You're welcome. Yup, exactly. After canceling the two initial terms and then dividing by $x^2$, you'll see that terms of degrees higher than $2$ will go to $0$ because $x \to 0$.

Comment: By the way, the index $k$ in the sum should start from $0$. I can't edit my comment after 5 minutes, so it's too late to fix it. But I hope you already know that the summation over $k$ starts from $0$, not $1$.